# Retrieve name of output arguments within a function

Tags: matlab

It is possible to use the function `inputname` to retrieve the workspace variable name passed in the call to the currently executing function. However, is there any equivalent function to obtain the name of the output arguments specified in the call to the currently executing function?

Imagine I have the following function:

```
function [a,b,c] = test(x)
disp([ouputname(1),ouputname(2),ouputname(3)])
end
```

When running this function:

```
[my,name,is] = test(x)
```

The expected result should be:

```
mynameis
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simply**: ***no there isn't.***

**Complicated**: Matlab code is "compiled" on run-time, and there is no way, that it knows `[my,name,is]` before it returns the result of `test(x)`.

---

**Workaround**: if you want to ensure, that the strings used within the function are equal to the variables returned to the workspace, you can do the following using [**`assignin`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html):

```
function test(x, varnames)

a = 1;
outputname{1} = varnames{1};
assigin('base', outputname{1}, a)

...

c = 3;
outputname{3} = varnames{3};
assigin('base', outputname{3}, c)

disp([outputname{:}])

end
```

and call your function like:

```
text(x,{'my','name','is'})
```

and you will have exactly this variables in your workspace afterwards and your function output:

*"mynameis"*